# Java SWT - dissolve (fade) from one image to the next

Tags: java, image, graphics, swt

I'm pretty new to Java and SWT, hoping to have one image dissolve into the next. I have one image now in a Label (relevant code):

```
Device dev = shell.getDisplay();
try {
    Image photo = new Image(dev, "photo.jpg");
} catch(Exception e) { }

Label label = new Label(shell, SWT.IMAGE_JPEG); 
label.setImage(photo);
```

Now I'd like `photo` to fade into a different image at a speed that I specify. Is this possible as set up here, or do I need to delve more into the `org.eclipse.swt.graphics` api?

Also, this will be a slide show that may contain hundreds of photos, only ever moving forward (never back to a previous image)---considering this, is there something I explicitly need to do in order to remove the old images from memory?

Thanks!!

Comment: I never worked with SWT, but in AWT/Swing you can use http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/AlphaComposite.html for this purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not aware of any swt widgets that directly support this type of functionality, your best bet would be to extend `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas` and adding a `org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintListener` that can handle drawing 2 overlapping images with a different alpha.  So something like this:

```
addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
    public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
        e.gc.setAlpha(50);
        e.gc.drawImage(image1, 0, 0);
        e.gc.setAlpha(100);
        e.gc.drawImage(image2, 0, 0);
    }
});
```

After that you would just have to create a thread change redraw your Canvas and change the images/alpha values at some interval.

---

As for your question about removing an `Image` from memory that is done by calling `dispose()` on the `Image` object, letting it get garbage collected won't be enough when using swt.